# FAKE.Deploy fails with error - Could not find file matching *.fsx in .\deployments/{project}\active

Tags: deployment, f#-fake

I'm quite new to FAKE. I was able to quickly write build script to compile a .net based MVC 4 application and was able to generate a nuget package as well.
But when I try to do a remote deploy of the created nuget package on a remote server, I get the below error:

`System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file matching *.fsx in .\deployments/{Project}\active
   at Fake.DeploymentHelper.unpack(String workDir, Boolean isRollback, Byte[] packageBytes)
   at Fake.DeploymentAgent.runDeployment[a](String workDir, a args, HttpListenerContext ctx)
   at Fake.HttpListenerHelper.routeRequest(FSharpFunc 2 log, HttpListenerContext ctx, IEnumerable 1 routeMatchers)`

This error clearly says that I have to have some sort of deploy.fsx packaged along with the nuget package. But i couldnt find any documentation/samples with respect to this aspect.

If someone could point out some specific examples of how to deploy using FAKE.Deploy or any other open source deployment tool integration with FAKE scripts?

Comment: If you put a .fsx script into your nuget package and name it `deploy.fsx`, `install.fsx` or `setup.fsx` and it will be executed on deploy.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, found out that Fake.Deploy requires a ***.fsx*** file to be present in your nuget package. Packaging it with an empty ***.fsx*** should work if you don't need to do anything post-deployment.